# Is that possible, to solve a complex mongoose populate query?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have four tables.
#First table

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
#First table
var studentSchema=new Schema({
  student_name: { type: String, required: true },
  sendKey: { type: String },
  created_by: { type:String },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Student',studentSchema);
```

#Second table

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var institutionSchema=new Schema({
  institution_name: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  email: { type:String },

  created_by: { type:String },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Institution',institutionSchema);
```

#third table

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
// var Institution = ('./institution');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var batchSchema=new Schema({
  batch_name: { type: String, required: true },
  institution: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Institution' },

  created_by: { type:String },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Batch',batchSchema);
```

#Fourth Table

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var batchtudentSchema=new Schema({
  student_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student', required : true},
  batch_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Batch', required:true},
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('BatchStudent',batchtudentSchema);
```

I have an institution Id. I want to `find` all students of this institution with Batch details.
Primarily I have tried to.. do that.

```
Student.find().populate('BatchStudent').pupulate('Batch').populate('Institution').exec((err, docs) => {
    console.log(docs)
    res.json(
        {
            data:docs
        }
    )
})
```

It is not working.. sending just all student data.. How can I get the data correctlly?

Comment: Can I see what you're getting?

Comment: [
        {
            "_id": "5f7c970b3b5ef43c6923e48d",
            "student_name": "asdf",
            "sendKey":"54333dsf",
            "created_at": "2020-10-06T16:10:51.578Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-06T16:10:51.579Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "543534dfdsdfg4ddfsgdf6564",
            "student_name": "asdf",
            "sendKey":"asdasd3432",
            "created_at": "2020-10-06T16:10:51.578Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-06T16:10:51.579Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]

Comment: You didn't have any property on the Student schema as BatchStudent referencing the BatchStudent schema, hence find returns the student list. I'll post a sample model to use in such scenario

Comment: can you please re-write my code or give an example of the whole procedure to handle this kind of situation.  @Xcode

Answer (score 0):

```
// Student Schema
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var studentSchema=new Schema({
  student_name: { 
   type: String, 
    required: true 
  },
  sendKey: { 
    type: String
  },
  batchStudent: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'BatchStudent', 
  }
  created_by: { 
    type:String
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now
  },
})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Student',studentSchema);

// BatchStudent Schema
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var batchtudentSchema=new Schema({
  student_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Student', 
    required : true
  },
  batch_id: { 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Batch'
  },
  institution: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Institution'
  }
 })
module.exports=mongoose.model('BatchStudent',batchtudentSchema);

// Institution Schema
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var institutionSchema=new Schema({
  institution_name: { 
    type: String, 
    lowercase: true
  },
  email: { 
     type: String
  },
  created_by: { 
     type:String 
  }
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Institution',institutionSchema);
```

If the I removed created_at and updated_at to avoid duplication. Obey DRY principles always (Don't repeat yourself)

If you need to get the document you can simply use Deep Population/Association for that as shown below:

```
Student.find({}).populate({
    path : 'batchStudent',
      populate : {
        path : 'institution'
      }
    }).exec(function (err, res) {
     // do whatever you need to do here
   })
```